# how to increase table view height dynamically according to collection view height in swift 3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

Here I am having a design like shown below in which I had designed all the cells except last cell in which it is having a collection view in which I need to load data and this is having pagination so how to give height for this cell when the collection view height increases dynamically depending on my array count. can anyone help me how to give height dynamically or any suggestions/ideas to implement this ?

Given the following structure:

> TableView
>
> > Table view cell
> >
> > Table view cell
> >
> > TableViewCell
> >
> > > CollectionView
> > >
> > > > CollectionViewCell
> > > >
> > > > CollectionViewCell
> > > >
> > > > CollectionViewCell
> > > >
> > > > [...variable number of cells or different cell sizes]

Comment: Try `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0; // set average estimated height`

Comment: but collection view increases how table view cell height knows with as you said @Priya

Comment: Add all required constraints to collection view inside tableview cell it will automatically increase its height according to content.

Comment: have u checked by giving constraints to table view cell by embedding collection view it won't increase table view cell height @Priya

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Set table view row height to automatic dimension
   `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44`
2. Create IBOutlet for the height of `collectionView` inside `tableViewCell`. Set `leading`, `trailing`, `top`, `bottom` constraint for `collectionView` inside `tableViewCell`.
3. Create outlet for `collectionView` under `tableViewCell` (like objCollectionView) and add following code inside `cellForRowAt indexPath` method

   ```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! tableCell
           cell.frame = tableView.bounds
           cell.layoutIfNeeded()
           cell.objCollectionView.reloadData()
           cell.objCollectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = cell.objCollectionView.contentSize.height
           return cell;

   }
   ```

This will automatically adjust the height of `tableViewCell` depends on the content it.

Comment: I need to implement pagination for the collection view inside table view cell is it possible ?

Comment: Yes its possible to do pagination also

Comment: what is scroll direction of your collectionView

Comment: vertical direction

Comment: what are the issue u facing?

Comment: it didn't expand table view cell according to collection view height

Comment: Have u added correct constraint to tableViewCell? Also have you set tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44

Comment: got it bro thanks I forget to change height in my height for row at index path method to UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902441/how-to-implement-pagination-for-collection-view-in-table-view-cell-in-swift-3 here is my question how to implement pagination in my case @Hemant Sabale

Comment: I hav faced layout cell height issue for the first load which is now solved from this answer by adding this code : 
`cell.frame = tableView.bound`

Thank you for saving my time.