# How to implement pagination for collection view in table view cell in swift 3?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

Here I am having layout in which one of my table view cell consists of collection view and in this I need to implement pagination and I am unable to use `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)` this function now how to implement pagination for table view can anyone help me how to implement this to place condition when it reaches last element of my collection view and here I know how to implement pagination but how to call the function which needs to reload ?

Here is my function which used to detect the last cell and make to reload the data by using below function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let obj = items
        let lastElement = (obj.count) - 1
        print(lastElement)
        if !loadingData && indexPath.row == lastElement {
            loadingData = true
            guard let obj = self.listClassModel else { return }
            if ((obj.searchCriteria.pageSize as? Int) != nil) {
                self.collectionView.bottomRefreshControl?.beginRefreshing()
                let viewController = HomeViewController()
                viewController.loadMoreData()
            }
        }
func loadMoreData() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            guard let obj = self.listClassModel else { return }
            let  totalItems = obj.totalCount
            let numberOfItems = obj.searchCriteria.pageSize as! Int
            let float = Float(totalItems)/Float(numberOfItems)
            print(float)
            let totalPages = Int(ceil(float))
            print(self.count)
            if totalPages != self.count {
                self.index += 1
                self.count += 1
                print(self.count)
                    let batchSize = 10
                    let sortField = "name"
                    let sortOrder = "ASC"
                    let conditionType = "eq"
                    let categoryId = 1
                    self.listCategoryDownloadJsonWithURL(listUrl: listUrlWithParameters)
            }
            else {
                self.loadingData = false
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // this runs on the main queue
                self.loadingData = false
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. Set table view row height to automatic dimension

tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44

2.Create IBOutlet for the height of collectionView inside tableViewCell. Set leading, trailing, top, bottom constraint for collectionView inside tableViewCell.

3.Create outlet for collectionView under tableViewCell (like objCollectionView) and add following code inside cellForRowAt indexPath method

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! tableCell

    cell.frame = tableView.bounds
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.objCollectionView.reloadData()

    cell.objCollectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = cell.objCollectionView.contentSize.height
    return cell;
```

}

This will automatically adjust the height of tableViewCell depends on the content it.

Comment: now I need to implement the pagination for collection view in table view cell here how I can check the condition for last item of collection view and need to reload how to place it I am asking @Hemant Sabale

Comment: yes it helped n marked as answer in my previous question

Comment: my problem resolved for constraints to increase table view cell but for  pagination not resolved if possible please help me bro

Comment: What is type of pagination? Horizontal or Vertical.

Comment: If its vertical then there is actually no need of pagination. The tableViewCell height goes on increasing depending on contentOffsetSize of UicollectionView. So there is no any pagination at all if collection scrollView direction is vertical . If its horizontal make sure collectionView item width is set to collectionView width and paging is enabled through storyboard.

Comment: vertical only and here only ten items must be loaded  for the first time but when ever it reaches last item then I need to call Json function changing parameters and need to reload collection view here how to check it reached to last item condition ?

Comment: in my given url only ten items must be loaded from service and after making call again second set of items will be loaded